# How do I assign a hostname to a dynamic IP address assigned by DHCP?

Tags: dns, dhcp, hostname, hosts

On my home network, the IPv4 address changes regularly, probably because when my computer got turned off, another computer was assigned to the same address so when I started my computer, there was an IP conflict leading to an automatic change of the IP address on my laptop.
I can assign "Jonathan-Linux.local" to 192.168.0.12 for example, but it won't change automatically when the IP address of my computer automatically changes. How do I assign it to an IP address that changes by DHCP?
Not sure that it would work to assign the DNS name of 127.0.0.1. I want remote access to any DNS name in the hosts file that I want to be found by remote access.
Say I put a host wordpress.Jonathan-Linux.local, which I would use wordpress.org on. And ftp.Jonathan-Linux.local. I want remote access to those domains.
On Windows, the NetBIOS name and the DNS suffix for that NetBIOS domain, is found remotely, even when the IP address automatially changes by DHCP.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than dynamically changing those hostnames, it would be simpler to configure your devices with static IPs.